# Field / Direct Sum Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=\mathbb R^n$ and define
$$V_1=\{x\in V\mid x_1+\dots+x_n=0\}$$
$$V_2=\{x\in V\mid x_1=\dots=x_n\}$$
Show that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces of $V$ and that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$. Find an example where this fails if we replace $\mathbb R$ by some other field $F$.

I'm having some trouble with the last part, to find where the direct sum fails when we replace $\mathbb R$ with another field. Any tips to lead me in the right direction?

Comment: How about examining carefully your proof for the real case?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1):

$V_1$ is of dimension $n-1$ and $V_2$ of dimension $1$. Their sum $V_1+V_2$ is therefore direct iff their intersection only contains the zero vector.

Thus an example where $V_1+V_2$ is not a direct sum follows. Let $F$ be the finite field on $2$ elements and $n=2$. $V_2$ only has $2$ elements, $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, and both are contained in $V_1$, which means that $V_1+V_2=V_1\ne V$ (indeed, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are not in the sum).

Comment: This example works but finding a vector that is not in $V_1$ or $V_2$ does not tell you that it's not in their direct sum.

Comment: @DionelJaime Edited. Is this better?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand this point.For  ≥2, the vectors with exactly two coordinates 1 and the rest 0 are in both 1 and 2, could you please explain this further?

Comment: @explodedstar In a direct sum, all non-zero vectors must lie in exactly one of the two addends, which is not the case here.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. This might be a dumb question but how does the vector with two coordinates 1 and rest 0 lie in 1 and 2? I cant seem to see how it lies in both of the subspaces

Comment: @explodedstar Please see my edit.